# Algorith/ Equation to get the ith element in N x N

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, natural-numbers, cross-product

I am having a difficulty figuring out the equation to get the ith element in $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ ( crossing the set of natural numbers).We have $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} = \{ (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(2,2)\dots\}$ if we traverse the matrix with a diagonal.Can someone help me in getting this equation ?

I want to do a small program that takes index $i$ , and return the $i$th element in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.This will be used for demonstration

Comment: Please explain your problem a bit better, perhaps with a simple example. For example, what output should your program show for $i=1$ to $i=5$? I mean what's the order rule by which $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ is built?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OEIS sequences [A002260](http://oeis.org/A002260) and [A004736](http://oeis.org/A004736)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got your question and you can find several solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779199/traverse-matrix-in-diagonal-strips